# cant fetch data through axios in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

i am building a react native app, through rest-api in django framework, in test mode or in expo go the code is working fine but in, but after the apk build , data is not fetching

```
const fetchDataFromAPI = async (code) => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    if (ipAddress && profileCode) {
      try {
        const apiUrl = `http://${ipAddress}:8000/api/stock/?i=${profileCode}&s=${code}`;
        setError(apiUrl);
        const response = await Axios.get(apiUrl);
        const stockData = response.data;
        setData(stockData);
      } catch (error) {
        setError('error in fetching');
        setData();
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    } else {
      setError('Ip Address Not Found');
    }
  };
```

after build always getting error in fetching
the total code in git repo is in following

https://github.com/pruthviraj-vegi/Ssc-React-Native

Comment: Do you create an instance for axios that's why you use axios like this ```Axios.get(apiUrl);```? not this ```axios.get(apiUrl);```? Or maybe it won't work when your app is running on a device that's not on the same network as your django server.